# Missng NPM installer

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently installed nodeJS and can see that it is there:

$ node -v
v14.17.0

but when I call npm it is missing:

$ npm -v
bash: /home/smoczyna/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm: No such file or directory

what is wrong here, I'm sure I had it before, how can I reinstate it now ? Or maybe better, how to reinstall whole NodeJS again instead ?

When I try this: nvm install v14.17.0 it says I already have it

Answer (score 0):

Is Npm installed, What kind of OS do you use, is it linux

You could try:

```
ls /usr/bin | grep npm
```

Comment: I was installed together with NodeJS  but it is missing now. It is Linux box

Comment: I also hae something called NVM which I suspect to make the mess

Comment: are you sure npm is installed, what does the above command outputs?

Comment: and everything is installed locall so not in /usr/bin  but /home/smoczyna

Comment: yes, I'm sure it was installed and still have its .npm folder locally indicating it was here

Comment: Is that so, then what is the path of your nodejs or nvm binary?

Comment: you can try: "which node" and "which npm"

Comment: /home/smoczyna/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/  inside this folder I just got: ng and node, there is no npm. I beleive it was removed when tried to upgrade it

Comment: can I just delete the folder with Node and start over again ?

Comment: yes I can, problem solved, delete and install again helps

Answer (score 0):

In case of any issue with node, npm, ng commands (after upgrade or so) it is enough to delete the folder with node installation entirely and run the installer again.